# Delphi Firemonkey InputQuery

Tags: delphi, dialog, firemonkey

The edit box of the dialog of InputQuery does not have focus when called on Mac OS, user will need to click the edit box before they can enter text. This does not happen on Windows as target platform.
Does anybody know a way around this or any other identical/similar dialog function which actually work?

Comment: If it were me, I'd implement my own form for that.

Comment: Yes, I guess I will have to do my own. Pity that there are so many bugs in Firemonkey.